# Merge two samba PDC and do master slave keeping data on two servers

Tags: ldap, samba, domain-controller

I need to do a very difficult thing.
I have this situation:

1) server A , with zentyal as samba PDC, 500 users in his ldap. Each user has an home that is mapped to H: . Several computers are connected to it.

2) server B: same as server A

Now I need to do this:

1) server P, samba PDC with all 1000 ldap users. No computers connect directly to it, no data is present.
2) server C, samba BDC slave of P. It has 1000 users but it contains the homes of 500 users.
3) server D the same of C.

Users of server C now can walk in a pc under server D and login and found their H: and viceversa.

Big problems:

1) uid of C and D conflicts. It is easy to replace uids on ldap (because ldif is a text file). But how can I mass remap uid of homes when I rsync/cp/tar the data from B to D?

2) user homes are half in server C and half in server D. When a server C user goes in server D how he can see his home (the data is on server C).

Are there better/other ways to do it?

Thanks,
Mario